# Postgres return the total number of rows only once

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, a posts table and a comments table. I'm trying to select all the comments to a post, I already have a query for this which works. I've simplified the query to just return the comment id.

simplified posts table:

| post_id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'randomuser' |
| 2 | 'randomuser1' |

simplified comments table:

| comment_id | post_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'cool post' |
| 2 | 2 | 'cool post1' |

The query looks like:

```
SELECT comment_id, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.comment_id = comment_id) as comment_count 
FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1;
```

This query will return all the comments that equal a specific post id and will return the total count of all comments. The problem is that this query is returning the total number of comments to a post with every comment.

ie:

| comment_id | comment_count <- this is being returned for every comment, I'm trying to return it only once |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

The problem is in my query as I specify to get the count of comments for every comment however I'm trying to only return the comment_count only once. As I'm writing this I think it would make more sense to just make another query for the comment count however I'm curious if there is a way.

Comment: Please provide sample data. What do you mean "return the comment_count **only once**"? And wouldn't you want the first column to be `post_id`?

Comment: The table in my question kinda showed what I was talking about. You can see the comment_count column is showing up for every row when I only want it to receive it only once. I'm not sure if I'm doing this the proper way but I'll update my question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need group by. I'm not sure about all your column names. Try

```
SELECT
  comments.comment_id
  SUM(likes.likes) NoLikes,
  SUM(comments.comment_count) comments
FROM
  likes 
JOIN
  comments  on likes.comment_id = comments.comment_id
GROUP BY 
  comments.comment_id;
```